# cannot find symbol (java compile time error)

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I am running my servlet program on tomcat server. I want to perform some jdbc activities in it.
I hv added that connector jar file in lib folder of tomcat(require for jdbc).I  hv posted the code here..

```
     import java.io.*;
 import javax.servlet.*;
 import javax.servlet.http.*;
 import java.sql.*;


 public class showAccounts extends HttpServlet
 {
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)


  throws IOException, ServletException
  {
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


 Connection con;
 Statement st;
 ResultSet rs;

 try
  {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://teamindia:3306/forjava?user=root&password=123");

   st=con.createStatement();
  rs=st.executeQuery("select * from users");


 while(rs.Next())
{
  out.println("<li>"+rs.getString(1));
  }
con.close();
  }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
 out.println(e); 
 }
  out.close();

 }

 }
```

while compiling...
I am getting this error

```
  error: cannot find symbol
  while(rs.Next())
      ^
  symbol:   method Next()
  location: variable rs of type ResultSet
```

what's the problem?

Comment: It's `next()` not `Next()`.

Comment: @Rohit Jain yahh...:D thnkyu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29) is having `next()` not `Next()`